# HOWTO debug Python logging config file errors

Tags: python, logging

I've added Python's logging module to my code to get away from a galloping mess of print statements and I'm stymied by configuration errors.  The error messages aren't very informative.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HDAudioSync.py", line 19, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('../conf/logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/config.py", line 162, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 5 arguments (21 given)
```

Nothing in my config file gives 21 arguments.

Here is the config file

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main, sftp, jobapi

[handlers]
keys=console, logfile, syslog

[formatters]
keys=simple, timestamp

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=logfile

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console, logfile, syslog
propagate=1
qualname=main


[logger_sftp]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console, logfile, syslog
propagate=1
qualname=sftp


[logger_jobapi]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console, logfile, syslog
propagate=1
qualname=jobapi

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simple
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_logfile]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=timestamp
args=('../log/audiosync.log')


[handler_syslog]
class=FileHandler
level=WARN
formatter=timestamp
args=('../log/audiosync.sys.log')

[formatter_simple]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_timestamp]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s -%(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

and here is the logging init code in my main module:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

logging.config.fileConfig('../conf/logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('main')
```

I'm not so much looking for what I did wrong here (though that would be nice) as for a methodology for debugging this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can dig into the Python source code to investigate these sorts of problems. Much of the library is implemented in Python and is pretty readable without needing to know the inner details of the interpreter. [hg.python.org](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a8f3ca72f703/Lib/logging/config.py) provides a web interface to the repository that is convenient for browsing. I couldn't find the branch for 2.6 but the relevant statement is on line 147 in the current revision.

You can see that `args` is generated from an eval which is getting the value of the `args` key from each `handler_*` section of the config file. That args variable is then expanded with an unpack (*) operation to create arguments for klass().

In your config file you have this line:

```
args=('../log/audiosync.log')
```

It is a 20-character string that is being unpacked into a tuple of individual characters which, along with the `self` object passed to `__init__`, accounts for the 21 arguments in the error message. You are missing a trailing comma needed to make a 1-element tuple:

```
args=('../log/audiosync.log',)
                            ^-- missing
```

The same bug is in the `handler_syslog` section.

Comment: Thank you!  I am returning to python after years of not using it and I'd forgotten about this odd, if arguably logical behavior of python tuple notation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Look for keywords

The last two lines of the traceback contain the word `handler` (`handler = ...` and `_install_handlers`). That gives you a starting point to look at the handler definitions in your config file.

#### Look for matching values *everywhere*

If a function takes 5 arguments, but you've somehow given over 4x that amount, something was not parsed the way you expected it to be. Especially when a quick glance at your config file doesn't show anything near that number.

I've found one of the biggest causes of this kind of discrepancy is passing a string when a function is expecting a list, tuple, or object. The underlying code may split that string into characters and use that for arguments.

In your case, the first option I can find is in this block in your config:

```
[handler_syslog]
class=FileHandler
level=WARN
formatter=timestamp
args=('../log/audiosync.sys.log')
```

There are no 21 character strings by themselves, but if you strip out the leading `../` from the args, you are left with `log/audiosync.sys.log` which is a 21 character string.

#### Use a debugger

That's what they're there for. Use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), or a visual debugger like [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/%E2%80%8E) or [PyDev](http://pydev.org/). Then, you can step through the code line by line, and check variable values throughout.

#### Change the logging level

Some modules allow you to set their logging level. You can set it to `DEBUG` to see everything the developers have ever set to log. It can help you to follow the flow of the application as it runs. I don't think this is available for the ConfigParser module, but it is available at times.

#### If all else fails, read the source

[The Python source code is available online](http://hg.python.org/). If you're getting semi-cryptic tracebacks and find it difficult to obtain context, you can always download the source, and run through the code manually.

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying "../" is a no-no?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't actually test it. I was just going through the steps that I would use to debug.

Comment: You could try hardcoding a path in there and see what happens.