# Python Logging: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to use the standard library `logging` module, using a config file to organise the loggers.

I tried a simple setup like so:

Config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main,second

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, exportHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,exportHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[logger_second]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,exportHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_exportHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
filename='LogBookmain.log'


[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

File1

```
import logging
import logging.config
import os

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('main')

os.system('test2.py')
logger.info('script was executed correctly')
```

File2

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('second')

a = 8
b = 4

result = a + b
logger.debug('result of a + b is '+ result)
result2 = a / b
logger.debug('result of a / b is '+ result)
```

but I get an error when I try running the second file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\\Logging\test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

  File "C:\\anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 79, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)

  File "C:\\anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 145, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

When I look up the error message on google, it only talks about python classes, but I'm not trying to write my own class here. What went wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by copying and pasting **starting from the line that says** `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my bad, it's now updated

Comment: As indicated by the full stack trace, the problem occurs while parsing the `logging.conf`, and has nothing to do with subsequent code. Thus, the next step is to try to edit the `logging.conf` down to a [mre] and figure out what part of it actually causes the problem. My guess is that there's a `filename=` line missing somewhere. This is definitely an area where the standard library can be improved; an error condition like this should be caught and interpreted for you.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to simplify my logging.conf.
Also thanks for reformatting my question, I'm not a native speaker, and having proper example on how to properly ask is great !

Comment: Your English is quite good, honestly; but Stack Overflow has some very particular expectations - because this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to read like they're part of a FAQ - because they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two errors in my `logging.config`:

1. For `Logger_main` and `logger_second`, the `qualname` had the same name ('simpleExample'), and refers to nothing in use.
2. Error in the Handler declaration:

```
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
filename='LogBookmain.log'
```

to the correct :

```
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('LogBookmain.log',)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021864/howto-debug-python-logging-config-file-errors) question helped me a lot, especially on how to define the `args`, and see how a working config looked like.

Comment: Ouch! That `args` tuple is painful. Well, live and learn! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

I *think* you wanted

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf',
                          defaults={'logfilename': 'LogBookmain.log'})
```

It's either 'logfilename' or 'filename'.
Or similarly adjust the config file.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried with both 'logfilename' and 'filename', with the same result. I guess it's time for me to thin down my config file to catch the error.